# Array grouping dynamically with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const task = [
    { x: 1, y: 20 },
    { x: 2, y: 30 },
    { x: 1, y: 50 },
    { x: 2, y: 20 },
    { x: 1, y: 10 },
    { x: 9, y: 40 },
    { x: 1, y: 30 },
    { x: 3, y: 5 }
];
```

there are two conditions:

- grouping limit can be max z
- sums of y can be max t

For example `z=2` and `t=60`(I am passing these values as parameters to a function), the result should be:

```
let result = [
    [{ x: 1, y: 20 },{ x: 2, y: 30 }],
    [{ x: 1, y: 50 }],
    [{ x: 2, y: 20 },{ x: 1, y: 10 }],
    [{ x: 9, y: 40 }],
    [{ x: 1, y: 30 },{ x: 3, y: 5 }]
];
```

I have managed to implement with `for` loop but i am curious about possible functional solutions. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You want the items to stay in the original order?

Comment: @trincot, yes, the order is important.

Comment: What do you mean by `functional` ? Paradigms are not very well defined...

Comment: @NenadVracar, It was typo, updated, Thanks

Comment: Then why are those two objects in last array with `y` sum of 70?

Comment: Sorry, somebody edited the code made mess. I am fixing

Comment: @serkan in such a case you could simply *rollback* the edit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *slightly more functional* approach would include some very simple *pure* helpers. Let's start with a function `ySum` that returns the sum of all `y` properties within given argument `group`:

```
const ySum = (group) => group.reduce((sum, { y: currY }) => sum + currY, 0);
```

Next, let's define a function that takes a task and a group and tells us whether the given task would fit in the also given group:

***Update from comments** This function always returns true for empty groups to prevent the empty array problem when `y > 60` for a certain task*

```
const taskFitsInGroup = (task, group) => {

    if (group.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return (group.length < 2) && (ySum(group) + task.y <= 60);
};
```

*Note: you can of course extract the constants `2` and `60` to variables / arguments.*

---

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a perfect candidate for the data transformation you require. The following line should do what you require, after `addTask` is implemented:

```
const result = tasks.reduce(addTask, [[]]);
```

Only thing left to do is create the `addTask` function that we give to `reduce` above. Using the helper functions we already created, this is actually pretty straightforward:

```
const addTask = (accumulation, task) => {

    const lastGroup = accumulation[accumulation.length - 1];

    if (taskFitsInGroup(task, lastGroup)) {
        lastGroup.push(task);
    } else {
        accumulation.push([task]);
    }

    return accumulation;
};
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const tasks = [
    { x: 1, y: 80 },
    { x: 2, y: 30 },
    { x: 1, y: 50 },
    { x: 2, y: 20 },
    { x: 1, y: 10 },
    { x: 9, y: 40 },
    { x: 1, y: 30 },
    { x: 3, y: 5 },
];

const ySum = (group) => group.reduce((sum, { y: currY }) => sum + currY, 0);


const taskFitsInGroup = (task, group) => {

    if (group.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return (group.length < 2) && (ySum(group) + task.y <= 60);
};


const addTask = (accumulation, task) => {

    const lastGroup = accumulation[accumulation.length - 1];

    if (taskFitsInGroup(task, lastGroup)) {
        lastGroup.push(task);
    } else {
        accumulation.push([task]);
    }

    return accumulation;
};

const result = tasks.reduce(addTask, [[]]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This has the same drawback as my original solution. If `tasks[0].y > 60`, then the result will have an empty array as it's first element.

Comment: @CRice I have updated the `taskFitsInGroup ` function with an additional check for empty groups. This fixes the problem. Note: `tasks[0].y === 80` now in the snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a helper array for the actual group and sum the property `y` together with the `y` property of the actual object

```
group.reduce((s, { y }) => s + y, o.y)
^^^^^                                  array
              ^                        accumulator for sum
                 ^^^^^                 destructuring to get y property
                           ^^^^^       build sum and return value
                                  ^^^  start accumulator with actual y prop
```

for checking against the given value.

```js
function group(array, z, t) {
    var result = [];
    array.reduce(function (group, o, i) {
        var sum = group.reduce((s, { y }) => s + y, o.y);
        if (i && sum <= t && group.length < z) {
            group.push(o);
        } else {
            result.push(group = [o]);
        }
        return group;
    }, []);
    return result;
}

var task = [{ x: 1, y: 20 }, { x: 2, y: 30 }, { x: 1, y: 50 }, { x: 2, y: 20 }, { x: 1, y: 10 }, { x: 9, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 30 }, { x: 3, y: 5 }],
    result = group(task, 2, 60);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another functional ES6 solution:

```js
function chunk(task, z, t) {
    return task.reduce( ({sum, arr, i}, {y}, j) => 
        (j > i && sum + y > t) || j - i >= z
            ? {sum: y, arr: [...arr, arr[arr.length-1].splice(j-i)], i: j}
            : {sum: sum + y, arr, i}
    , {sum: 0, arr: [task.slice()], i: 0}).arr;
}

const task = [{x:1,y:20}, {x:2,y:30}, {x:1,y:50}, {x:2,y:20},{x:1,y:10},{x:9,y:40},{x:1,y:30},{x:3,y:40}];

const result = chunk(task, 2, 60);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

NB: Note the extra `j > i` condition which makes sure that every sub array in the result will have at least one element, even if the `y` is greater than the limit. Otherwise you could have an endless loop -- never being able to place that element with a too great `y`-value.

#### Explanation

The function starts with creating the start value of the `reduce` callback:

```
{sum: 0, arr: [task.slice()], i: 0}
```

The `arr` property represents the result so far, which is the original array with all its elements combined together. The `slice` is necessary to make sure we have a copy of the array and don't mutate the original one.

The `sum` property will keep track of the sum in the last chunk up until the current index of the `reduce` loop.

The `i` property tells at which the index in the original array we made the last split into a new chunk.

The `reduce` callback has these parameters:

- `{sum, arr, i}`: this is the destructured representation of the object described above. The `reduce` callback will always return an object with these three properties, so they will serve again in the next iteration as arguments of the callback.
- `{y}`: again destructuring to extract the `y` value of the current element in the `task` array.
- `j`: the current index in the `task` array

Then the short expression syntax is used for the arrow function (`=>`): there is no statement block following it, just an expression, which is the return value of the callback.

This expression uses the ternary operator which decides whether the current element can stay in the current chunck, in which case only the `sum` needs to be updated, while the `arr` and `i` properties can remain the same. The short ES6 object notation is used to express that the `arr` property will get the `arr` value. Same for `i`:

```
: {sum: sum + y, arr, i}
```

The other case is when a new chunk must be split of:

```
? {sum: y, arr: [...arr, arr[arr.length-1].splice(j-i)], i: j}
```

Here the `splice` method is used to remove all elements from the current last chunk after the `i-j` first elements there. The deleted elements are put back in a new array, as the last, new element of it. The rest is reproduced with `...arr`. I have to admit that this is not purely functional, since the last subarray of `arr` is being mutated with `splice`. But writing the same with `slice` would require more code.

The condition to decide which of the two actions to take, reflect the conditions you specified: `y > t` and `j - i >= z`. I already explained why I added `j > i` to the first condition.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one potential solution using `.reduce`:

```js
var task = [{x:1,y:20}, {x:2,y:30}, {x:1,y:50}, {x:2,y:20},{x:1,y:10},{x:9,y:40},{x:1,y:30},{x:3,y:40}];

// grouping limit can be max z
// sums of y can be max t

// the result should be:
// [[{x:1,y:20}, {x:2,y:30}],[{x:1,y:50}], [{x:2,y:20},{x:1,y:10}],[{x:9,y:40}],[{x:1,y:30},{x:3,y:5}]];

function sumY(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.y, 0);
}

function group(maxSize, maxSum, arr) {
    return arr.reduce((groups, item) => {
        const last = groups[groups.length - 1];
        (!last || last.length >= maxSize || sumY(last) + item.y > maxSum)
            ? groups.push([item])
            : last.push(item); 
        return groups;
    }, []);
}

console.log(group(2, 60, task));
```

Comment: the result will have one extra element = [] if task[0].y>(MAX=60).

Comment: @Sphinx Yes. Good catch. I've edited the answer with a (dubious) fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
const group = (arr, z, t, result = [[]], count = 0, y = 0) => 
  (arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (
    count++, y += curr.y,
    count > z || y >= t 
      ? (count = 0, y = curr.y, result[result.push([curr]) - 1])
      :  (acc.push(curr), acc)
  ), result[0]), result);
```

Thats a purely functional approach. Call it with `group(task, 2, 60)`. However i would still prefer the good old for loop:

```
 const result = [];
 let group = [], z = 2, t = 60, count = 0, y = 0;

for(const task of tasks){
  if(count++ >= z || (y += task.y) >= t){
    count = 0;
    y = task.y;
    result.push(group);
    group = [];
  }
  group.push(task);
}
if(group.length) result.push(group);
```

Comment: You *have* heard of [stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), right?

Comment: @JonasW., 25K rep and you don't know? Wow, you have been missing out on a nice feature here for a long time.

Comment: @trincot was rather sarcastic ... but yes i can't use it as it is not available on mobile devices yet

Comment: Ah OK that explains it -- missed the sarcasm  :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` method and use one variable for current array number and one for current `y` sum value.

```js
const task = [{x:1,y:20}, {x:2,y:30}, {x:1,y:50}, {x:2,y:20},{x:1,y:10},{x:9,y:40},{x:1,y:30},{x:3,y:40}];

const group = (data, z, t) => {
  let n = 0, tTemp = 0;
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if ((r[n] && r[n].length >= z) || (tTemp + e.y) > t) n += 1, tTemp = e.y;
    else tTemp += e.y;
    r[n] = (r[n] || []).concat(e)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = group(task, 2, 60)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const task = [{x:1,y:20}, {x:2,y:30}, {x:1,y:50}, {x:2,y:20},{x:1,y:10},{x:9,y:40},{x:1,y:30},{x:3,y:40}],
z = 2, t = 60;

const group = task =>
  task.reduce((a, e) => (
    !!a.length && a[a.length - 1].length < z &&
    a[a.length - 1].reduce((s, {y}) => s + y, e.y) <= t ?
    a[a.length - 1].push(e) : a.push([e])
  ) && a, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(group(task)))
```